# do messages sent to HWND_BROADCAST go to other desktops?

Tags: windows, message

I'm trying to determine some of the details of how `HWND_BROADCAST` works. Unfortunately, MSDN doesn't have a specific page for this value; it's only mentioned in passing in several other articles, such as the ones for [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) and [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx).

What I specifically want to know is whether messages sent to `HWND_BROADCAST` are received by windows associated with other desktops in the same window station. The docs say the message will go to "all top-level windows in the system", but clearly that can't be strictly true. For instance, I'm sure they wouldn't go to windows in other logon sessions (e.g. on a terminal server). My guess is that they are at least limited to the window station of the calling process, but I don't know if they are also limited to the desktop of the calling thread (each thread is associated with a single desktop).

Worst case I can go write some code to test this empirically, but does anybody happen to know the answer already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  Messages sent in this manner will only go to the top-level windows of the currently logged in windows session/desktop.  They will not go to any other desktop.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Vista will block the message to be delivered to top-level windows  if it comes from a lower privileged process, you should care of it.